# APEX CPU Limit Exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, cpu

I am currently receiving an APEX CPU Limit Exceeded error when trying to save work orders. This is happening with any field updated. The error received is RG_WorkOrderTgr: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded. Any insight I can get from the community would be greatly appreciated. I have posted the code from RG_WorkOrderTgr below

```
trigger RG_WorkOrderTgr on WorkOrder (before insert,before update, after insert) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
        RG_WorkOrderCloseHandler.recursionFlag = false;
        RG_WorkOrderCloseHandler.ticketcloseDateUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, Trigger.isInsert, false);
        WorkOrderSendEmailHandler.sendEmailAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
        System.debug('Trigger.isInsert after'+Trigger.isInsert);

    } else if ( Trigger.isUpdate && RG_WorkOrderCloseHandler.recursionFlag && !RG_WorkOrderCloseHandler.isUpdateRecursive) {
        RG_WorkOrderCloseHandler.isUpdateRecursive = true;
        RG_WorkOrderCloseHandler.recursionFlag = false;
        RG_WorkOrderCloseHandler.ticketcloseDateUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, false, True);
        System.debug('Trigger.isUpdate after'+Trigger.isUpdate);
    }

    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore) {
            Map<Id,WorkOrder> casemap = new Map<Id,WorkOrder>();
            RG_WorkOrderPriorityFiedlMappingCls.priorityFiedlMappingBeforeInsert(Trigger.new,casemap, true);
            System.debug('Trigger.isInsert before '+Trigger.isInsert);
        }

        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            Map<Id,WorkOrder> casemap = new Map<Id,WorkOrder>();
            if(Trigger.oldMap!=NULL)
                casemap = Trigger.oldMap;

            RG_WorkOrderPriorityFiedlMappingCls.priorityFiedlMappingBeforeInsert(Trigger.new,casemap, False); 
            //RG_WorkOrderCloseHandler.ticketcloseDateUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap, false, true);
            if(WorkOrderSendEmailHandler.isUpdateRecursive!=NULL && !WorkOrderSendEmailHandler.isUpdateRecursive){
                WorkOrderSendEmailHandler.isUpdateRecursive = true;
                WorkOrderSendEmailHandler.sendEmailAfterStatusUpdate(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
            }

            System.debug('Trigger.isUpdate before '+Trigger.isUpdate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Apex CPU time limits are notoriously challenging to debug because it's often not the code identified in the error message that's actually the problem. The CPU time limit is cumulative across the entire transaction, meaning your Workflow Rules, Processes, Flows, and all triggers and other Apex code run during the transaction. Reviewing the analytics panes in your Developer Console _may_ help you identify areas where inordinate amounts of time are being consumed.

Comment: You can help us help you, to the extent possible, by identifying potential performance trouble spots in your trigger handler and in any declarative automation, and sharing those elements.

Comment: Thank You both. Based on what I posted above where would you suggest I add the debug statements?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I run into CPU limits and can't seem to figure out what is taking up the most time I fall back on old faithful... the [limits class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm).

In this case, the trigger is likely just the straw that broke the camels back and not the action that is taking up the majority of the CPU limits.

You will likely need to add debug statements to other Apex classes to figure this out. Of most interest to you will be: `Limits.getCpuTime()` and `Limits.getLimitCpuTime()`.

My personal favorite is utilizing both to display a percentage:

```
    Decimal allowed = System.Limits.getLimitCpuTime();
    Decimal current = System.Limits.getCpuTime();
    .
    .    // Code that does work
    .
    System.debug('CPU limit used: ' + (allowed / current) + '%');
```

Comment: Thank You for the info. Im not a coder so I am not 100% sure where to add these

Comment: Heres the link to the [Apex trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_intro). This is a good starting point for new developers. Learning how to debug problems like this can be complex even for experienced devs. I would contact whoever wrote this code - a third party, a senior dev, whoever. If none of those are available, its time to learn how to write some code the hard way.

Comment: At a guess, I'd assume theres a problem with the recursion statements provided in the code - either causing recursion or failing to prevent recursion. Recursion is a statement causing itself to re-run continuously until a limit is reached, ie, the CPU limit exception you're seeing. You'll have to dig through the code referenced in this trigger to try & spot what exactly is causing this to run in loops essentially.